# Preserving red part on Android Camera Preview and other part on screen is Grayscale

Tags: android

I am writing a android app about camera.
The function I want to implement is let preview preserving red color on screen, 
the other part on screen be `grayscale`.

Like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E59FR.jpg)

I use the particular scalar multiply R, G and B component to attach grayscale 
and preserve red part of preview after changeing raw data format to RGB.
but after I override onDraw(Canvas canvas) method in my custom View,
the result is like blue filter [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2aMK.jpg)

Can anybody give some hint to let me know which step I am wrong.

THANK YOU.

The code of my custom View is below

```
    package com.example.macampreviewdemo;
    public class CamPreviewDemoActivity extends Activity {   
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
            int h, w;
            public String tag = "tag";
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.i(tag, "onCreate");
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);        
            h = metrics.heightPixels;
            w = metrics.widthPixels;                        
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);        
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                     Display display = ((WindowManager) 
                            getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
                 setContentView(R.layout.main);
             setRequestedOrientation(0);
                     ViewToDraw dtw = (ViewToDraw) findViewById(R.id.vtd);
             CameraView cameraView = new CameraView(this, dtw, w, h);
            ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(cameraView);

            }

    }
```

And this:

```
    package com.example.macampreviewdemo;

    public class ViewToDraw extends View{
    public String tag = "tag";
    public byte[] image;    
    public boolean isCameraSet = false; 
    public int imgWidth, imgHeight;     
    Bitmap overlayBitmap;
    Matrix matrix;

public ViewToDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    matrix = new Matrix();
}

public void cameraSet(){
    isCameraSet = true;
}

public void putImage(byte[] img){
    image = img;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    Log.i(tag, "onDraw() ");
        int size = imgWidth * imgHeight;      
        int[] rgb = new int[imgWidth * imgHeight];
        if(isCameraSet){                
            rgb = convertYUV420_NV21toARGB8888(image, imgWidth, imgHeight);
            for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
        if(Color.red(rgb[k]) == 255 && 
                       Color.green(rgb[k]) == 0 && 
                       Color.blue(rgb[k]) == 50){}
        else{
            rgb[k] = (int) (
                                        (0.2126 * Color.red(rgb[k])) + 
                    (0.7152 * Color.green(rgb[k])) + 
                        (0.0722 * Color.blue(rgb[k]))
                                        );                       
        }
    }

    Log.i("tag", "rgb length = " + rgb.length);  
        overlayBitmap = 
                Bitmap.createBitmap(rgb, 0, imgWidth, 
                                    imgWidth, imgHeight, 
                                    Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    canvas.drawBitmap(overlayBitmap, matrix, null);
    overlayBitmap.recycle();
        }
}

static public void decodeYUV420SP(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {
    final int frameSize = width * height;
    int rtmp, gtmp, btmp;
            for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
                int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
                    int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
                    if (y < 0)y = 0;
                    if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                            v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                            u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                    }

                    int y1192 = 1192 * y;
                    int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
                    int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
                    int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

                   if (r < 0)r = 0;
                   else if (r > 262143)r = 262143;

                   if (g < 0)g = 0;
                   else if (g > 262143)g = 262143;

                   if (b < 0)b = 0;
                   else if (b > 262143)b = 262143;

                   rtmp = ((r << 6) & 0xff0000);
                   gtmp = ((g >> 2) & 0xff00);
                   btmp = ((b >> 10) & 0xff);       
                   rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) 
                                        | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
            }
     }
}

int[] yuv420ToGrayScale(byte[] yuv420, int width, int height){
    int size = width * height;
    int y1, y2, y3, y4;
    int[] pixel = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i+=2) {
            y1 = yuv420[i]&0xff;;
            y2 = yuv420[i + 1]&0xff;;
            y3 = yuv420[i + width]&0xff;;
            y4 = yuv420[i + width +1]&0xff;;    

            pixel[i] = yuv420[i];
            pixel[i + 1] = yuv420[i +1];
            pixel[i + width  ] = yuv420[width + i];
            pixel[i + width + 1] = yuv420[i + width + 1];

            if (i!=0 && (i+2)%width==0)
                i+=width;

    }

    return pixel;
}

/**
 * Converts YUV420 NV21 to ARGB8888
 * 
 * @param data byte array on YUV420 NV21 format.
 * @param width pixels width
 * @param height pixels height
 * @return a ARGB8888 pixels int array. Where each int is a pixels ARGB. 
 */
public static int[] convertYUV420_NV21toARGB8888(byte [] data, int width, int height) {
    int size = width*height;
    int offset = size;
    int[] pixels = new int[size];
    int u, v, y1, y2, y3, y4;

    // i along Y and the final pixels
    // k along pixels U and V
    for(int i=0, k=0; i < size; i+=2, k+=1) {
        y1 = data[i  ]&0xff;
        y2 = data[i+1]&0xff;
        y3 = data[width+i  ]&0xff;
        y4 = data[width+i+1]&0xff;

        v = data[offset+k  ]&0xff;
        u = data[offset+k+1]&0xff;
        v = v-128;
        u = u-128;

        pixels[i  ] = convertYUVtoARGB(y1, u, v);
        pixels[i+1] = convertYUVtoARGB(y2, u, v);
        pixels[width+i  ] = convertYUVtoARGB(y3, u, v);
        pixels[width+i+1] = convertYUVtoARGB(y4, u, v);

        if (i!=0 && (i+2)%width==0)
            i+=width;
    }

    return pixels;
}

private static int convertYUVtoARGB(int y, int u, int v) {
    int r,g,b;

    r = y + (int)(1.402f*u);
    g = y - (int)(0.344f*v + 0.714f*u);
    b = y + (int)(1.772f*v);
    r = r>255? 255 : r<0 ? 0 : r;
    g = g>255? 255 : g<0 ? 0 : g;
    b = b>255? 255 : b<0 ? 0 : b;
    return 0xff000000 | (r<<16) | (g<<8) | b;
}

public static void myNV21ToRGB(int width, int height){
    int yy, u, v;
    int frame_size = width * height;

        }
    }
```

And this:

```
package com.example.macampreviewdemo;
    public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    public Camera mycamera;
    List<Camera.Size> cameraSize;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;  
    public ViewToDraw vtd;
int pickedH, pickedW;
int defaultH, defaultW;
public String tag = "tag";

public CameraView(Context context, ViewToDraw _vtd, int width, int height) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mHolder = getHolder(); 
    mHolder.addCallback(this); 
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); 
    vtd = _vtd;
    defaultH = height;
    defaultW = width;

}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
    Log.i("tag"," surfaceCreated");
    int i;

    mycamera = Camera.open(); 
    cameraSize = mycamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    if(cameraSize != null){
        // pick resolution
        pickedH = defaultH;
        pickedW = defaultW;

        for(i=0;i<cameraSize.size();i++){
            if(cameraSize.get(i).width < defaultW){
                break;
            }else{
                pickedH = cameraSize.get(i).height;
                pickedW = cameraSize.get(i).width;
            }
        }

    }else{
        Log.e("tag","null");
    };
    try {
        mycamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);  
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    Log.i("tag","surfaceChanged");
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mycamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(pickedW, pickedH);
    mycamera.setParameters(parameters);

    //create buffer
            PixelFormat p = new PixelFormat();
            PixelFormat.getPixelFormatInfo(parameters.getPreviewFormat(),p);
            int bufSize = (pickedW*pickedH*p.bitsPerPixel)/8;

            //add buffers
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
            mycamera.addCallbackBuffer(buffer);                            
            buffer = new byte[bufSize];
            mycamera.addCallbackBuffer(buffer);
            buffer = new byte[bufSize];
            mycamera.addCallbackBuffer(buffer);

            mycamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new PreviewCallback() {
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) { 
            Log.i("tag", "onPreviewFrame");
            Log.i("tag", "pickedH = " + pickedH);
            Log.i("tag", "pickedW = " + pickedW);
            vtd.putImage(data);
            vtd.cameraSet();
            vtd.imgHeight = pickedH;
            vtd.imgWidth = pickedW;

            vtd.invalidate();

            mycamera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
        }
    });
    mycamera.startPreview();
}


@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.i("tag", "surfaceDestroyed");
    mycamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    mycamera.release();
    mycamera = null;
}
    }
```

And this:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".CamPreviewDemoActivity" >

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/FrameLayout01"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/preview">
            </FrameLayout>

            <com.example.macampreviewdemo.ViewToDraw
                    android:id="@+id/vtd"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

    </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```